# Probability of two (or more) specific characters in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My strings are invalid if it contains `aa` anywhere as a substring, that is, a specific character two or more times in a row.

What's the probability of a valid string given `c` possible characters and a string length of `n`, each string being equally likely?

Comment: If the string is `aba`, is it valid?  How is the string composed?  Of alphabets, or alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @GNUSupporter I think the answer makes it perfectly clear that `aba` is valid (since no character appears two or more times in a row). And there are `c` possible characters.

Comment: @5xum Thanks for your explanation.  I misunderstood "in a row".

Answer (score 1):

We seek $\mathsf P(n,c)$, the probability that a string of length $n$ randomly generated from $c$ characters will not contain a specified character adjacent to itself.

We can ignore the identity of all $c-1$ characters save the specified character, call it `a`.   Let the $n$ character string be composed of characters `a` and `b` , where the probability that any particular character in the string is `a` is $1/c$.

The count for arrangements of $k$ `a` and $(n-k)$ `b` is $\binom n k$, and each has a probability weight of $(c-1)^{n-k}/c^n$.

However, the count for such arrangements where there is at least one `b` between every two consecutive `a` is: $\tbinom{\Box}{\Box}$.

Clearly $k$ cannot be more than the ceiling for half of $n$.   Then the weighted sum is thus:

$$\therefore \mathsf P(n,c) ~=~\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil} \dbinom{\Box}{\Box} \dfrac{(c-1)^{n-k}}{c^n}$$

Which *may* have a closed form.

Fill in the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Let us answer first to this other related question
*In how many ways can we dispose $m$ characters $a$ in $n$ places such that 
none of them are contiguous ?*

We consider the ordered couple $ax$, where $x$ is one whichever of the remaining $c-1$ characters,
acting as a separator. So however we place some of this couples inside a word, we are sure that the $a$'s won't "touch" each other.

Thus it is clear that we can compose a word respecting the above requisites as per the following scheme
$$
\underbrace {\overbrace { \cdots x \cdots ,\left( {ax} \right),\; \cdots x \cdots ,\left( {ax} \right),\, \cdots }^{n\;\text{char}}}_{m\, \cdot \;\left( {ax} \right)}\; + 
\;\underbrace {\overbrace { \cdots x \cdots ,\left( {ax} \right),\; \cdots x \cdots ,\left( {ax} \right),\, \cdots }^{n - 1\;\text{char}}}_{\left( {m - 1} \right)\, \cdot \;\left( {ax} \right)}a
$$

The relevant number is 
$$
\begin{gathered}
  N_{\text{nc}} (n,c,m)\quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  \;0 \leqslant n,m \hfill \\
  \;1 \leqslant c \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - m \\ 
  m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - m}  + \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - 1 - \left( {m - 1} \right) \\ 
  m - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - 1 - \left( {m - 1} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - m \\ 
  m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - m \\ 
  m - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - m}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - m + 1 \\ 
  m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - m}  = \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 - m \\ 
  n + 1 - 2m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - m}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

and of course the answer to your question will be the sum of that for $m$ that goes from $0$ to $n$,
which is actually limited to $\left\lfloor {\left( {n + 1} \right)/2} \right\rfloor  = \left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil $.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
p(n,c) = \frac{{N_{\text{nc}} (n,c)}}
{{c^{\,n} }} = \frac{1}
{{c^{\,n} }}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,m\, \leqslant \,\,\left( {\left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil \, \leqslant \,\,n} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - m + 1 \\ 
  m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {c - 1} \right)^{\,n - m} } 
}$$

An example, for $n=4, \, 5$ is given in the figure

[image: String_rep_char]